# Flot line graph messing up data for x-axes and y-axes

Tags: flot

I am making a line graph in Flot, but i can't manage to put x-axes and y-axes to display data normally, they are stick together. How can i make it to be over whole graph. I didn't find in any documentation how to fix that.

This need to be on left side outside of graph : [0.24, "0.24 USD"], [2085.95, "2085.95 USD"]

and this on bottom of a graph
[0, "0"], [1, "Jan"], [275, "Aug"], [549, "Mar"], [823, "Oct"], [1097, "Jun"], [1371, "Dec"], [1372, "Dec"]

Here is an image how it looks now, all is grouped on bottom left corner
[image]

And this is how it need to looks like, this is image from Flot website
[image]

Here is a code:

```
var data1 = [{chart_data_money}];

var dataset = [{
    data: data1,
    color: '#ffa500',
    label: 'Loss in USD',
    points: { symbol: "circle", fillColor: "#FF000;", show: true}
}];

var options = {
    series: {
      lines: { show: true },
      points: { 
        radius: 1,
        fill: true,
        show: true 
      }
    },
    xaxes: [{ 
        position: "bottom",
        ticks: '{chart_xticks_money}',
        color: "black",
        axisLabel: "Sin(x)",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 3
    }],
    yaxes: [{
        position: "left",
        color: "red", // lines colors for y axes
        ticks: '{chart_yticks_money}',
        axisLabel: "Sin(y)",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 3
    }],
    legend: {
      noColumns: 0,
      labelFormatter: function (label, series) {
          return "<font color=\"white\">" + label + "</font>";
    },      
      // legend postion and color      
      backgroundColor: "#000",
      backgroundOpacity: 0.9,
      labelBoxBorderColor: "orange",
      position: "nw"
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 3,
        mouseActiveRadius: 50,
        backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }, // 2 colors gradient for bg of chart
        axisMargin: 20
    }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
  $.plot($("#graph-line"), dataset, options);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you give Flot your axis ticks as string instead of array:

```
ticks: '{chart_xticks_money}',
```

needs to be

```
ticks: {chart_xticks_money},
```

and the same for the other axis.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n978nw23/) has the same error as your image, and this is the [correct version](https://jsfiddle.net/n978nw23/1/) without the `'`.

Comment: If i use it like that i got error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ," i already try it, and if i look for that error i got this in console "ticks: [0, "0"], [1, "Jan"], [275, "Aug"], [549, "Mar"], [823, "Oct"], [1097, "Jun"], [1371, "Dec"], [1372, "Dec"]," so probably is that last "," where is error

Comment: You are missing the outer brackets for the array, change to: "ticks: [[0, "0"], [1, "Jan"], [275, "Aug"], [549, "Mar"], [823, "Oct"], [1097, "Jun"], [1371, "Dec"], [1372, "Dec"]]," (see the second fiddle I linked).

Comment: ah i need to use it like this ticks: [{chart_xticks_money}] was missed [ ] before adding a array